# Planning to Make Strength & Conditioning Routine for Martial Arts

Tags: workout-routines, routine, martial-arts

New to lifting and wanna start. Would appreciate if anyone could check my planned routine real quick.

I wouldn't mind lowering my body fat percentage. But I'm mostly looking to improve athleticism for martial arts. Still gonna practice technique, of course. As someone with no previous experience in sports, think I could go for extra strength and conditioning, though.

More specific goals:

• Lower body fat percentage, to help with agility.

• Be able to throw a reverse punch and return to fighting position quickly and explosively.

• Be able to throw hook and roundhouse kicks to opponent's head without stumbling over myself.

• Touch grass.

Planning two days per week. Cause my martial arts training is three to four days a week. Wonder if I can do these back to back.

Upper body/lower split. Should target most, if not all, muscle on upper/lower body.

Here are the exercises [and my rationale for picking them].

**Upper Body:**

• Bent Over Barbell Row [Core strength, stability]

• Kettlebell Swing [Balance, cardio, explosiveness, flexibility]

• Landmine Press [Rotational strength, stability]

• Wood Chop [Core strength, explosiveness, rotational strength]

• Cable Crunch [Core strength, stability]

**Lower Body:**

• Romanian Deadlift [Core stability, mobility, stability]

• Sumo Squat [Core strength, balance, mobility, ROM]

• Bulgarian Split Squat [Balance, flexibility]

• Hamstring Curl [Balance, mobility]

• Push Press [Balance, coordination, flexibility]

No particular order here. Suggestions on how to order them? Planning on descending pyramid sets.

Not sure about the split, though. Most of these seem like compound exercises, so the split feels kinda arbitrary. Both seem like full body workouts, ngl.

As to why there's no cardio or stretching. Both are part of the strength and conditioning at our club. This is for extra S&C that I can't get there.

Comment: Lowering body fat %: that is simply a matter of energy expenditure > calories consumed (AKA calorie deficit). Just increasing your activity level (especially with strength training) you might see some results.